# ts-node cannot find installed node module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, ts-node

This is a multipart question so sorry if the title is misleading.

**My Problem**:
When running `npx ts-node --project npm-scripts/tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register npm-scripts/npm-start.ts` and going through my start scripts I am getting the error `Error: Cannot find module 'my-types'`, and I think it is coming from `ts-node` and not `webpack`. I am assuming I have some configuration wrong somewhere.

**What I am trying to achieve:** My goal is to import the `enum` and `const` from `my-types`. I have a private typescript library `my-types` I am maintaining that almost exclusively exports `.d.ts` files that I have installed with `npm` in my main repo called `my-app`. Within these `.d.ts` I have one `const` and one `enum`. See below for an example.

```
# my-types index.d.ts
export const TURTLE = 'Turtle'
export enum FuzzyMammals {
   CAT = 'cat',
   DOG = 'dog'
}

export type Pet = FuzzyMammals | typeof TURTLE
```

```
# my-app
import {FuzzyMammals} from 'my-types'; <-- no linting errors, command+click works fine
```

**What I have tried**: Using this library has worked in the past until I recently added the `enum` and `const`. Originally I had `enum FuzzyMammals` and `const TURTLE` along side my other types in a `d.ts` file, but I don't think this is right since neither an `enum` nor a `const` are types. I have also tried importing them as `import type {FuzzyMammals} ...` which does not work, so I moved them to an `index.ts` which also did not work. I'm sure theres some proper combo of `tsconfig.json` and exporting correctly I am missing here.

Additionally if I `import {FuzzyMammals}...` and then click on `FuzzyMammals` from `my-app` it will open the `node_modules/my-types` to the right location, so as far as my IDE is concerned I've installed it correctly and the code can find the right location for the types, just not my compiler.

`my-types` code:

```
File structure:
| index.d.ts < export everything from types
| types/
   | index.d.ts < export everything from subfolders
   | subfolder/
      | index.d.ts
```

```
#tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "module": "esNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "paths": {
      "my-types/*": ["types/*"]
    },
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

```
#package.json
{
 ...other stuff,
 "files": [
    "types/**/*.d.ts",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
"type": "module"
}
```

`my-app` code:

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "scripthost"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "assumeChangesOnlyAffectDirectDependencies": true,
    "module": "esNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "paths": {
      "js/*": ["src/js/*"],
      "styles/*": ["src/styles/*"],
      "test/*": ["test/*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./test/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./src/vendor.js", "node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

```
/* the start scripts do a lot of env checking so npm start will run
* npx ts-node --project npm-scripts/tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register npm-scripts/npm-start.ts
*
* and npm-scripts/tsconfig.json looks like
*/

{
  // extend your base config so you don't have to redefine your compilerOptions
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./*.ts", "./**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "paths": {
      "js/*": ["src/js/*"],
      "appConfig": ["src/js/typings/appConfig.d.ts"]
    },
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

The reason I think it is `ts-node` and not `webpack` is because the error occurs in my scripts prior to running `webpack`.

If you would like to see anything please ask.